# can we merge more than two dataframes using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-science

I have tried something like this.  **pandas.merge(df1,df2,df3,df4,how='inner',on="key")** but it throws an error.

Comment: check reduce merge ~

Comment: pd.concat(list_of_dfs)